# Can Kestrel listen on a specific foreign adress?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm starting to learn C # and try to develop an app which run on Ubuntu using Kestrel.

Now netstat command show next:

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

As far as I understand the server accepts requests from any foreign address, but I want it from only specific

I tried to google this question, but found only options for how to change the local address, not a foreign one

Please give advice

Comment: You can use iptables, and allow only the ip's you want to access the port 5000.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to filter the IP from inside your C# code?

Comment: You can override host and port with an environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://foo.bar:1234`. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#server-urls)

Comment: Kalten, i tried .UseUrls, it changes local adress, not foreigh